# Automatic compilation of a variable number of fields in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good morning,
I would need to create a button that through JAVASCRIPT automatically fills in the INPUT, SELECT AND RADIO fields of the HTML page (this is a registration form).
The number of these fields is not known, it varies from case to case.

In the INPUT fields the button should automatically insert the text TEST, while for the SELECT and RADIO fields select the first available.

The button should then recognize how many INPUT, SELECT and RADIO are present in the HTML page and fill them in automatically.

Who could help me?
Thanks so much!

Here an example:

```
<form id="booking_guests" method="post" class="needs-validation" novalidate="" action="/it/booking/guests/book/" data-next-booking-step="/it/quote/proceed/">


  <div class="booking-one-room">
    <div class="room_recap">
      <h2>Camera 1</h2>
      <p>1 adulto</p>
    </div>


    <div class="collapse-cont" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#guest1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="guest1">
      <p>Ospite 1: Adulto</p>

      <input type="hidden" name="room[1][person:1][type]" value="Adults">
      <input type="hidden" name="room[1][person:1][typeBook]" value="Adult">
    </div>

    <div id="guest1" class="booking-one-guest collapse show" aria-labelledby="guest1" data-parent="#guest1">

      <div class="form-group d-md-flex justify-content-md-between">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <label>Titolo *</label>
          <select class="form-control brs_input-form" name="room[1][person:1][title]" required="">
            <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Seleziona</option>
            <option value="Mr">
              Sig.
            </option>
            <option value="Mrs">
              Sig.ra
            </option>
          </select>


        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group d-md-flex justify-content-md-between">
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <label>Nome *</label>
          <input type="text" class=" form-control brs_input-form" name="room[1][person:1][name]" required="" value="">


        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group d-md-flex justify-content-md-between">
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <label>Cognome *</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control brs_input-form" name="room[1][person:1][surname]" required="" value="">


        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group d-md-flex justify-content-md-between">
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <label>Data di nascita *</label>
          <input type="hidden" class="form-control brs_input-form db1 flatpickr-input" name="room[1][person:1][birthday]" min="1921-04-28" max="2003-04-28" required="" value="2003-04-10"><input class="form-control brs_input-form db1 input" placeholder=""
            required="" tabindex="0" type="text" readonly="readonly">


        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group d-md-flex justify-content-md-between">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <label>Sesso *</label>
          <select class="form-control brs_input-form" name="room[1][person:1][gender]" required="">
            <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Seleziona</option>
            <option value="Male">
              Maschile
            </option>
            <option value="Female">
              Femminile
            </option>
          </select>


        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group d-md-flex justify-content-md-between">
        <div class="col-md-7 brs_radio-check">
          <input class="form-control lead_check" type="radio" name="leading" id="radio1" value="1:1">
          <label for="radio1">Intestatario pratica</label>


        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="lead_extra_fields" style="display: block;">

        <div class="form-group d-md-flex justify-content-md-between">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <label>Paese *</label>
            <select class="form-control countrySelect brs_input-form required-to-lead" name="room[1][person:1][country]" required="">
              <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Seleziona</option>
              <option value="1">
                Italia
              </option>
              <option value="2">
                Spagna
              </option>
              <option value="3">
                Germania
              </option>
              <option value="4">

            </select>


          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group d-md-flex justify-content-md-between">
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <label>Indirizzo *</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control brs_input-form required-to-lead" name="room[1][person:1][address]" value="" required="">


          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group d-md-flex justify-content-md-between">
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <label>Codice postale *</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control brs_input-form required-to-lead" name="room[1][person:1][zip]" value="" required="">


          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group d-md-flex justify-content-md-between">
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <label>Città *</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control brs_input-form required-to-lead" name="room[1][person:1][city]" value="" required="">


          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group d-md-flex justify-content-md-between">
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <label>Telefono *</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control brs_input-form required-to-lead" name="room[1][person:1][phone]" value="" required="">


          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group d-md-flex justify-content-md-between">
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <label>Cellulare *</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control brs_input-form required-to-lead" name="room[1][person:1][mobile]" value="" required="">



          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group d-md-flex justify-content-md-between">
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <label>Email *</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control brs_input-form required-to-lead" name="room[1][person:1][email]" value="" required="">

            <div class="invalid-feedback">^ Questo campo è obbligatorio, e deve indicare un indirizzo email valido</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group d-md-flex justify-content-md-between" style="display: none !important">
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <label>Codice fiscale *</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control brs_input-form cod-fis required-to-lead required-italy-only" minlength="16" maxlength="16" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z][0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z][0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]$" name="room[1][person:1][ssn]" value="">

            <div class="invalid-feedback">^ Questo campo è obbligatorio e deve contenere un codice fiscale valido</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-select-privacy">
          <div class="title">Preferenze di contatto</div>
          <p>Vorremmo inviarti degli aggiornamenti sulle ultime promozioni e novità di Imperatore.<br> A questo link puoi consultare la nostra <a class="privacy-link" href="/it/azienda/privacy/">politica sulla privacy</a>.</p>
          <div id="selected--zg-ul-select" class=""></div>
          <ul class="be-select zg-ul-select" tabindex="0">
            <li class="accept-contact-yes active"><a>Si, voglio ricevere aggiornamenti sulle novità di Imperatore</a></li>
            <li class=""><a>No, non voglio ricevere nessuna comunicazione</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="brs_filter-check">
          <input type="checkbox" id="el21" class="accept-contact" name="room[1][person:1][accept_post]" checked="">
          <label for="el21">post</label>
        </div>
        <div class="brs_filter-check">
          <input type="checkbox" id="el31" class="accept-contact" name="room[1][person:1][accept_email]" checked="">
          <label for="el31">email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="brs_filter-check">
          <input type="checkbox" id="el41" class="accept-contact" name="room[1][person:1][accept_phone]" checked="">
          <label for="el41">phone</label>
        </div>
        <div class="brs_filter-check">
          <input type="checkbox" id="el51" class="accept-contact" name="room[1][person:1][accept_sms]" checked="">
          <label for="el51">sms</label>
        </div>
        <div class="brs_filter-check">
          <input type="checkbox" id="el61" class="accept-contact" name="room[1][person:1][accept_marketing]" checked="">
          <label for="el61">marketing</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="room_submit">
    <input type="submit" class="book-extra brs_btn-primary-small" value="Procedi con il preventivo">
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Fill them in from what source? What have you tried and where are you stuck? Issue is far too broad as written. You really need to narrow this down to more specific issues within your higher level objective

Comment: As I have already explained above, In the INPUT fields the button should automatically insert the text TEST, while for the SELECT and RADIO fields select the first available.

Comment: The first of a group.

Comment: OK, overall not too difficult, now what have you tried? SO isn't a free code writing service. Objective is for you to show your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when you are stuck or attempt not working as expected

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  YOUR CODE HERE
    <button id="go">CLick me</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $("#go").on('click',function(){
        $("input[type='text'],input[type='email']").each(function(){
           $(this).val('Test'); 
        });
        
        $("select").each(function(){
           $(this)[0].selectedIndex = 1;      //change 1 for the index you want
        });

       $("div.brs_radio-check").each(function(){
          $( this ).children("input[type='radio']")[0].checked=true;
        });
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change "YOUR CODE HERE" for that html in your question

Comment: this is the most acceptable, since it's simple and flexible.

Comment: @Gigi Cigliano have you tried that? If it works please mark the answer as correct one to help people looking for this kind of situation.

Answer (score 0):

For the various types of inputs that aren't radios, checkboxes or hidden I would create an object with the dummy values for that type. Then loop over those inputs and set the value based on `type`.

For radios keep track of names encountered while looping over them so you only check the first.

For `<select>` filter the options that do have value and take the first one

```js
const $form = $('#booking_guests')

const values= {
   text: 'Test',
   email: 'foo@bar.com',
   number: 5,
   date: '2021-01-01'
}
// radios
const radioNames = new Set();
$form.find(':radio').each(function(){
   if(!radioNames.has(this.name)) {
      radioNames.add(this.name)
      this.checked = true;
   }
});
// select
$form.find('select').val(function(){
   const $optsWithValue = $(this).find('option').filter(function(){
        return this.value
   });
   return $optsWithValue.first().val()
})
// basic inputs
$form.find('input').not(':radio,:checkbox,:submit').each(function(){
    if(values.hasOwnProperty(this.type)){
       $(this).val(values[this.type])
    }else{
       // validate the type="hidden" has a value here
       // or any types I forgot to add to values object
       console.log('No matching type:', this.type)
    }   
});
// checkboxes
$form.find(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="booking_guests" method="post" class="needs-validation" novalidate="" action="/it/booking/guests/book/" data-next-booking-step="/it/quote/proceed/">


  <div class="booking-one-room">
    <div class="room_recap">
      <h2>Camera 1</h2>
      <p>1 adulto</p>
    </div>


    <div class="collapse-cont" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#guest1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="guest1">
      <p>Ospite 1: Adulto</p>

      <input type="hidden" name="room[1][person:1][type]" value="Adults">
      <input type="hidden" name="room[1][person:1][typeBook]" value="Adult">
    </div>

    <div id="guest1" class="booking-one-guest collapse show" aria-labelledby="guest1" data-parent="#guest1">

      <div class="form-group d-md-flex justify-content-md-between">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <label>Titolo *</label>
          <select class="form-control brs_input-form" name="room[1][person:1][title]" required="">
            <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Seleziona</option>
            <option value="Mr">
              Sig.
            </option>
            <option value="Mrs">
              Sig.ra
            </option>
          </select>


        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group d-md-flex justify-content-md-between">
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <label>Nome *</label>
          <input type="text" class=" form-control brs_input-form" name="room[1][person:1][name]" required="" value="">


        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group d-md-flex justify-content-md-between">
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <label>Cognome *</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control brs_input-form" name="room[1][person:1][surname]" required="" value="">


        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group d-md-flex justify-content-md-between">
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <label>Data di nascita *</label>
          <input type="hidden" class="form-control brs_input-form db1 flatpickr-input" name="room[1][person:1][birthday]" min="1921-04-28" max="2003-04-28" required="" value="2003-04-10"><input class="form-control brs_input-form db1 input" placeholder=""
            required="" tabindex="0" type="text" readonly="readonly">


        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group d-md-flex justify-content-md-between">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <label>Sesso *</label>
          <select class="form-control brs_input-form" name="room[1][person:1][gender]" required="">
            <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Seleziona</option>
            <option value="Male">
              Maschile
            </option>
            <option value="Female">
              Femminile
            </option>
          </select>


        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group d-md-flex justify-content-md-between">
        <div class="col-md-7 brs_radio-check">
          <input class="form-control lead_check" type="radio" name="leading" id="radio1" value="1:1">
          <label for="radio1">Intestatario pratica</label>


        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="lead_extra_fields" style="display: block;">

        <div class="form-group d-md-flex justify-content-md-between">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <label>Paese *</label>
            <select class="form-control countrySelect brs_input-form required-to-lead" name="room[1][person:1][country]" required="">
              <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Seleziona</option>
              <option value="1">
                Italia
              </option>
              <option value="2">
                Spagna
              </option>
              <option value="3">
                Germania
              </option>
              <option value="4">

            </select>


          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group d-md-flex justify-content-md-between">
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <label>Indirizzo *</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control brs_input-form required-to-lead" name="room[1][person:1][address]" value="" required="">


          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group d-md-flex justify-content-md-between">
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <label>Codice postale *</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control brs_input-form required-to-lead" name="room[1][person:1][zip]" value="" required="">


          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group d-md-flex justify-content-md-between">
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <label>Città *</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control brs_input-form required-to-lead" name="room[1][person:1][city]" value="" required="">


          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group d-md-flex justify-content-md-between">
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <label>Telefono *</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control brs_input-form required-to-lead" name="room[1][person:1][phone]" value="" required="">


          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group d-md-flex justify-content-md-between">
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <label>Cellulare *</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control brs_input-form required-to-lead" name="room[1][person:1][mobile]" value="" required="">



          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group d-md-flex justify-content-md-between">
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <label>Email *</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control brs_input-form required-to-lead" name="room[1][person:1][email]" value="" required="">

            <div class="invalid-feedback">^ Questo campo è obbligatorio, e deve indicare un indirizzo email valido</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group d-md-flex justify-content-md-between" style="display: none !important">
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <label>Codice fiscale *</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control brs_input-form cod-fis required-to-lead required-italy-only" minlength="16" maxlength="16" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z][0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z][0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]$" name="room[1][person:1][ssn]" value="">

            <div class="invalid-feedback">^ Questo campo è obbligatorio e deve contenere un codice fiscale valido</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-select-privacy">
          <div class="title">Preferenze di contatto</div>
          <p>Vorremmo inviarti degli aggiornamenti sulle ultime promozioni e novità di Imperatore.<br> A questo link puoi consultare la nostra <a class="privacy-link" href="/it/azienda/privacy/">politica sulla privacy</a>.</p>
          <div id="selected--zg-ul-select" class=""></div>
          <ul class="be-select zg-ul-select" tabindex="0">
            <li class="accept-contact-yes active"><a>Si, voglio ricevere aggiornamenti sulle novità di Imperatore</a></li>
            <li class=""><a>No, non voglio ricevere nessuna comunicazione</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="brs_filter-check">
          <input type="checkbox" id="el21" class="accept-contact" name="room[1][person:1][accept_post]" checked="">
          <label for="el21">post</label>
        </div>
        <div class="brs_filter-check">
          <input type="checkbox" id="el31" class="accept-contact" name="room[1][person:1][accept_email]" checked="">
          <label for="el31">email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="brs_filter-check">
          <input type="checkbox" id="el41" class="accept-contact" name="room[1][person:1][accept_phone]" checked="">
          <label for="el41">phone</label>
        </div>
        <div class="brs_filter-check">
          <input type="checkbox" id="el51" class="accept-contact" name="room[1][person:1][accept_sms]" checked="">
          <label for="el51">sms</label>
        </div>
        <div class="brs_filter-check">
          <input type="checkbox" id="el61" class="accept-contact" name="room[1][person:1][accept_marketing]" checked="">
          <label for="el61">marketing</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="room_submit">
    <input type="submit" class="book-extra brs_btn-primary-small" value="Procedi con il preventivo">
  </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
      $("input:text").val("TEST");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Here is my code, but i'm finding some problems with the radio and the select fields.